# Локальное свойство изменяет родительское Vue

Tags: vue.js

Имеется корневой экземпляр vm и используется для формирования иерархии отделов (из селектов):

```
var vm = new Vue({
   el: '#search-form',
   data: {
        departments: []
   },
   components: {
        'modal-selects': modalSelects
   },
   methods: {
        changeDp: function(data) {
            this.departments.splice(data.index + 1)
            // if(data.value != '' && data.value != '0') this.loadDepartments(data.value)
        }
   }
})
```

Имеется локально зарегистрированный компонент:

```
var modalSelects = {
    props: ['departments'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            dps: this.departments
        }
    },
    template: '#departments-modal-selects',
    methods: {
        changeDp: function(obj) {
            this.dps.splice(obj.index + 1)
            // if(obj.value != '' && obj.value != '0') this.loadDepartments(obj.value)
        }
    }
}
```

В компоненте входной параметр `departments` хочу использовать как начальное, и сохраняю его как локальное свойство в dps(как гласит документация) для дальнейших манипуляций.
Но! при вызове метода `changeDp()` локального компонента, обрезается и свойство departments корневого экземпляра - чего не должно быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Естественно. Ты же присваиваешь ссылку на prop departments. Возьми `slice()` от массива

```
data: function() {
    return {
        dps: this.departments.slice()
    }
},
```

Comment: Максим К Спасибо! Ох уж эти основы:)